# how to update multiple fields of a table using a sql statement in vb.net?

Tags: sql, vb.net, visual-studio, .net-4.0

When trying to update multiple fields using a form, I receive an error message "No value given for one or more required parameters." At the .ExecuteNonQuery() Could someone please clarify whether I should be using .AddwithValue for the fields I am updating; or for my "WHERE" field? (RunnerID) Thanks in advance

(I have a public class that sets up the database connection and I have imported Oledb and am able to update a Boolean field to True in another one of my forms. )

```
Private Sub ChangeBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ChangeBtn.Click
    conn.Open()
    Dim sqlQuery As String = "UPDATE tblPersonal SET Phone = @Phonetxt, Email = @Emailtxt, Age = @Agetxt, Full_Name = @Nametxt, Login_Key = @Passwordtxt WHERE RunnerID = @RunnerIDtxt"
    Dim sqlCommand As New OleDbCommand
    With sqlCommand
        .CommandText = sqlQuery
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phonetxt", Phonetxt.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Emailtxt", Emailtxt.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Agetxt", Agetxt.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nametxt", Nametxt.Text)
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passwordtxt", Passwordtxt.Text)
        .Connection = conn
        .ExecuteNonQuery()

    End With
    conn.Close()
End Sub
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear... you're missing a parameter binding for `@RunnerIDtxt`.

Comment: here's hoping @Passwordtxt isn't a plaintext password

Comment: Sorry about that.. I'm pretty new to Vb. I didn't understand that I needed to add parameter bindings for both the fields I'm changing and the field I'm referring to.

Comment: @SvampebobCameron To answer your secondary question, you need to provide a binding to *all* parameters that you specify in the query.

Comment: I'm really [not a fan of the AddWithValue() method](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided enough parameters.   Your query has 6 parameters, and you're only specifying values for 5 of them.

You need to provide a value for `@RunnerIDtxt`.

Comment: Do I need to specify a value for RunnerIDtxt?